# How to always generate different public key using RSA_generate_key 

Tags: c, unix, openssl, rsa

I've encountered a problem using `RSA_generate_key`. The method generate the same public key in two different C sources. So these two sources are a client and a server of an application, compiled and running (for now) on `localhost`. How can I generate a different pair every time RSA_generate_key is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From RSA_generatey key manual:

> The pseudo-random number generator must be seeded prior to calling RSA_generate_key().

You need call RAND_add with a start seed, if in linux you can read the seeds from /dev/random if you can wait for enough entropy or from /dev/urandom if you need a fast response.

You can learn more here:
http://research.swtch.com/openssl